# Horizontal 'accounting style' tables?

Tags: tabulator

Tabulator works great for column-oriented tables; that is tables that have a fixed number of columns and an increasing number of rows.

However, in the accounting world, tables are horizontal with a fixed number of rows and an increasing number of columns. When building an accounting-style table, time is expressed horizontally. See example:

[image]

Is it possible for Tabulator to support accounting-style/horizontal tables? Perhaps it already does but I just don't know how to configure that.

Answer (score 1):

You would just have to structure your data in a format that tabulator could understand.

So for each cost item you would create a row data object that would contain the data for that cost item, and then create a column for each of the quarterly results. we could use column groups to gain headers similar to your example

So your column definitions would look a bit like this:

```js
var columns = [
    {title:"Cost Item", field:"cost_item"},
    {title:"Description", field:"desc"},
    {title:"Budget", field:"budget", bottomCalc:"sum"},
    
    //define your quarters
    {title:"MAR18 - MAY18, columns:[
        {title:"Q1", columns:[
            {title:"HISTORIC", field:"q1", bottomCalc:"sum"},
        ]}
    ]},
    {title:"JUN18 - AUG18, columns:[
        {title:"Q2", columns:[
            {title:"HISTORIC", field:"q2", bottomCalc:"sum"},
        ]}
    ]}
];
```

And your rows would look a bit like this:

```js
var rows = [
    {cost_item:"A1", desc:"Directly incurred: Staff", budget:1000000, q1:20000, q2:20000},
    {cost_item:"A2", desc:"Directly incurred: Travel", budget:150000, q1:6000, q2:6000},
]
```

You can then set them on your table with:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table",{
    data:rows,
    columns:columns,
});
```